# How to detect when an App is force moved to SD-Card on rooted Android

Tags: android, root, sd-card

I have declared my App as internalonly, yet some rooted users move it to SD-Card.

How can I detect at run-time that this has happened? I do not trust the information that packagemanager is reporting as these are rooted phones and my app should not had been moved to SD-card anyways.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the application open /proc/self/maps and look for an entry that is an apk file and look at its path.

Why exactly are you concerned about this?  Hopefully it is because of a functional reason, such as problems if the SD card is unavailable.  Doing it for security purposes is of limited point on a rooted device.

If you detect it and complain, please have the error screen state why it is a problem. Just claiming "it's not allowed" or giving bogus reasons will only prompt people to figure out how to out-fake your fake-out detection and in the meantime leave you poor ratings in the market.

Comment: Thanks! This is not for security. I have a service and I backup some critical data to both App directory and SD-Card. I know the APP storage should be on internal, but I have error reports from the field that indicate otherwise. And yes, I will provide a understandable "warning screen", just once. No nagging.

Comment: If it's the app private storage you are concerned about, better to just examine the actual path you are writing to as it may well not be the same volume as contains the apk. I believe on official SD installs, private data still goes on /data, but not sure about on the unofficial implementations.  It may be true at the moment that an apk on /data implies private storage there as well, but that's not necessarily linked.