# Is it possible to track how many users have moved my app to SD card?

Tags: android, analytics, sd-card

I'm interested in the analytics of how many users have moved my application to the SD card. Is there a way to determine this data?  Ideally, I'd want to log an event that its been moved to the SD card (and vice-versa), but at this process is out with the application, I'm unsure how to go about getting what I want. For what its worth, I'm currently using Flurry for analytics.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the path of your application files when the application is started. Edit: I was thinking of checking the running executable path, however that doesn't seem to work.

Have you tried the answer to [How to detect when an App is force moved to SD-Card on rooted Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101240/how-to-detect-when-an-app-is-force-moved-to-sd-card-on-rooted-android) ?

Comment: If by "application files" you mean `getFilesDir()`, that should always be on internal storage. Those are not put on external storage. If you mean something else, could you be more specific?